# Image posts in Facebook-like-box is too big for the container

Tags: css, facebook, wordpress

We have a Wordpress website for our school and we wanted to integrate the FB like box on our sidebar.

Since the minimum width of the like box is 292-300px, we had to look for a plugin that can be reduced to less than the minimum set pixels. That said, we used the Facebook plugin by Weblizar because we can set the width of the box to 262px. (See [here](http://mymonol.com/aboutmonol/introduction/)). However, in the widget's stream, the images of our posts seem to extend beyond the container. We tried to change into different plugins, thinking it was a theme conflict and tried to look at the previews in the FB developers site but it seems that it's all the same.

We've read forums about custom CSS for the like box but it seems that a lot of the options eventually became useless because FB kept on changing something. Can you please give us any advice on how to customize the width of the image? It's not about the total width of the box at all because we tried to increase the width of our sidebar and tried testing it to a 600px width as well. The effects are still the same. Hope you can help us.

Comment: You should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no real minimum to the like box. Just generate a like box code from facebook developers [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages), and then paste into a regular wordpress text widget.

Now in order to resize it you will have to add inline styling like so:

```
<div style="width: 150px; overflow: hidden;" class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

I add a width of 150px to their demo code. You can also wrap this code in another div and give it a fixed height / width with an `overflow: hidden;`.

Just make sure you "cut it" in the width that doesn't cut the photos and this way it looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if the image overflow is the problem would be to target all images in the widget and give them a max-height and max-width percentage value so they won't overflow out of the box. You will have to test the percentages to find the right size.

You can add the following to your style.css file:

```
.fb-like-box > img {
  max-height: 40%; /* or whatever percent you find suitable */
  max-width: 40%;
}
```

The ".fb-like-box" is the class of your widget, the ">" selects children of the that widget and targets all "img"s inside.

One caveat is that this will only really work if the images you use are the same size and orientation.

Hope that helps if you still needed clarification!